# Angular5: Clarification on Observables and Subscription

Tags: angular, scroll, observable, subscription

I am currently trying to load data dynamically as I scroll down so that it does not at all have to load at once and instead loads piece by piece as the user scrolls. An image of this is below:

[image]

As it stands, on initialization of the component holding the math information on the right I use a subscription to bind the number of theorems showing on screen to what my service dictates. This is done like so:

**bible.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentChecked } from '@angular/core';
import { BibleService } from './bible.service';
import {Theorem} from '../../model/theorem';
import {ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bible',
  templateUrl: './bible.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bible.component.scss']
})
export class BibleComponent implements OnInit {

  allTheorems: Theorem[];
  filtered: Theorem[];
  @ViewChild('theoremList') elementView: ElementRef;

  constructor(private service: BibleService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.findAllTheorems()
      .subscribe(
        theorems => this.allTheorems = this.filtered = theorems
      );
  }

  search(search: string) {
    this.filtered = this.allTheorems.filter(theorem =>
      theorem.rule.includes(search) ||
       (theorem.name && theorem.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    ));
  }
}
```

**bible.service.ts**

```js
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Theorem} from '../../model/theorem';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class BibleService {

  pageSize = 10;
  private pageSizeSubscription;
  pageSizeChange: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();

  constructor(private af: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  findAllTheorems(): Observable<Theorem[]> {

    return this.af.list('theorems', ref => {
      return ref.limitToFirst(this.pageSize).orderByKey();
    }).valueChanges().map(Theorem.fromJsonList);

    // return this.af.list('theorems').valueChanges().map(Theorem.fromJsonList);

  }

  updatePageSize(num) {
    this.pageSizeChange.next(num);
  }

}
```

So in my bible.component.ts on init I call the service function named 'findAllTheorems' and subscribe to the returned value, so that my two Theroem arrays are filled with the returned value. **Side note** is my explination of what is happening with this subscription correct? And does that mean if the value being returned by 'findAllTheorems' changes then my arrays will dynamically update?

Anyways, I want to some how be able to dynamically change the value of pageSize in my service and have that update the page so that more theorems display as the user scrolls down? Is this the best way to do this? **Overall** What is the best way to dynamically load more items into the list as the user scrolls down so that every time they hit the bottom 10 more items load into the bottom? I also have a watcher that logs to the console whenever the bottom of the div is hit, meaning I could call a function to add more theorems whenever that is hit.

Also, what does findAllTheorems being an observable mean exactly? Is that essentially saying that this function is open to be subscribed to so that other functions or variables can watch for what it is out puting at all times to stay up to date?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your explanation of subscription is correct, but you do not seem to be storing the subscription anywhere, which means you cannot unsubscribe after the component is destroyed. It will cause a memory leak.

Try something like this:

```
 private subscription: Subscription;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.service.findAllTheorems()
      .subscribe(
        theorems => this.allTheorems = this.filtered = theorems
      );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

If you do not want to handle your subscriptions imperatively, try using an async pipe. It will handle the subscriptions for you. Check out the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

As for infinite scroll and dynamic loading of content I would use [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). Make sure to include a polyfill, because the global browser support is around 75% right now.

The basic implementation with AngularFire would be something like this:

1. Create InfiniteScroll directive which emits when user scrolls to the bottom of a page.
2. Use AngularFire's [dynamic querying](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md#dynamic-querying) to run a new query every time the InfiniteScroll directive emits.

Comment: Thanks for the help I will work on implementing dynamic querying. I understand why there is memory leak and why I need to unsubscribe but is the best place to do that on ngOnInit()? Because if I need the value to be updating as the component is up if I unsubscribe immediately on ngOnInit() won't it not keep tracking changes? If I am right what is the best way to unsubscribe when the application is closed (like when the users closes the tab or exits away or I end ng serve)? Thanks again.

Comment: Ah It was my typo. You need to subscribe in `ngOnInit()` and unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy()`. I've edited my answer.